# How to develop a Query Analyzer

Tags: asp.net, analyzer

I want to develop the application in which user write query into the text box when it click on the submit button it displays the results in the Grid just just in the Sql Server query analyzer tool i used VS 2008 and application develop in Asp.Net using C#.
                                                                           Thanks

Comment: Have you considered contacting a programmer? They are very good at this type of thing and would probably be willing to write it for you under contract.

Or perhaps you are a programmer and just looking for someone to do your job for you for free?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how advanced you want to have it. Most scenarios suffice with a single textbox in which the sql statement can be written, a button to submit it and a GridView control with AutoGenerateColumns="true" (the default) to display the requested data. In the codebehind you simply take the string from the textbox, use it as inline sql statement and use simple ADO.NET to connect with the database and bind the result to the GridView.

Comment: The point is that , How to parse the query before hitting database ?